# Retrieve Subscriber from a Suppression List

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap, suppressionlist

I'm trying to retrieve emails on a Suppression List using the SOAP API

Here is my SOAP Envelope

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    ...
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com">
      <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>ListSubscriber</ObjectType>
        <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
        <Properties>ListID</Properties>
        <Properties>Status</Properties>
        <Filter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ComplexFilterPart">
          <LeftOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
            <Property>ListID</Property>
            <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
            <Value>1234</Value>
          </LeftOperand>
          <LogicalOperator>AND</LogicalOperator>
          <RightOperand xsi:type="ComplexFilterPart">
            <LeftOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
              <Property>CreatedDate</Property>
              <SimpleOperator>greaterThanOrEqual</SimpleOperator>
              <Value>2018-04-15T15:49:21.707</Value>
            </LeftOperand>
            <LogicalOperator>AND</LogicalOperator>
            <RightOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
              <Property>CreatedDate</Property>
              <SimpleOperator>lessThanOrEqual</SimpleOperator>
              <Value>2019-04-15T15:49:36.913</Value>
            </RightOperand>
          </RightOperand>
        </Filter>
      </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This query works for other types of Lists, but not for Suppression Lists.

My query looks similar to the example on https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_all_subscribers_on_a_list.htm
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The subscribers on the suppression list can be queried like this as the suppression list is created as a data extension and not as a list. The external key can be found in the Auto-Suppression Configuration under Send Management in Email studio.

```
  <soapenv:Body>
  <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[External Key]</ObjectType>
        <Properties>Email Address</Properties>
        <Properties>Date Added</Properties>
        <Filter xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="q1:SimpleFilterPart">
           <q1:Property>Date Added</q1:Property>
           <q1:SimpleOperator>greaterThanOrEqual</q1:SimpleOperator>
           <q1:Value>2018-04-15T15:49:21.707</q1:Value>
        </Filter>
     </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

Best,
Mischel